# Is this routine okay for muscle building and strength

Tags: workout-routines

I workout in my home so i have to limit my self a bit for exercises.
i did biceps and triceps workout for a year only so i have decided to work all muscles including lower body and upper body.So following will be my weekly schedule

**Tuesday:** Legs and chest

- 4 sets of squats with weights
- 1 set of 20 reps bulgarian split squats without weights.
- 2 sets of push ups.
- 2 sets of dips.

**Wednesday:** Shoulders and abs

- 4 sets of sitting barbell press
- 1 set of bicycle crunches
- 1 set of iron butterfly.
- 1 set of toe touches.

**Thursday:** Biceps and triceps

- 5 sets of concentration dumbbell curl
- 1 set of standing dumbbell curl.
- 4 sets of tricep dips

Biceps and triceps will be hit twice a week.i want to know your suggestion and advices.
Will my routine going to be okay.
Thanks in adnaves

edit:
my goal is to get muscular without adding fat.

regards,
Asd.

Comment: Try calisthenics.

Comment: Question: You say you're hitting biceps and triceps twice a day - do you mean that you are doing additional lifting aside from what you've detailed in the Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday plans?

Comment: @john3103,Sorry,its twice a week.

Comment: Lookup "Bigger, Leaner, Stronger" by Mike Mathews, and start reading his blog muscleforlife.com.  The book will give you everything you need to know, and you can make your own decisions from there.

Comment: What is the rep count?  3x8 is my goto for building

Comment: reps are as much as i can do probably increasing progessively.

Comment: There's hardly any volume in your program. Building muscle (or revealing ig) and strength comes largely from diet and then volume and intensity play the next largest role. I'd recommend looking into increasing the volume that you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This workout is **OK**, but not great.

You'll certainly see progress if you're just starting out, but likely you'll stall-out after a while.

Here's a rundown of some improvements you could make:

**There's not quite enough volume.** 9-10 sets per workout isn't usually enough. Aim for 15-20.

**This is a bodypart-split.**
Ideally, each muscle-group would get trained 2-3 times per week. Here, your quads get a workout once, whereas hamstrings are completely ignored. You should add a deadlifting day.

**Too much isolation for your Bi's and Tri's.** Biceps and triceps are rather small muscles and working them isn't going to be as efficient as working bigger muscle-groups. Don't do bicep curls, do pull-downs/pull-ups/rowing. Swap the tricep dips for bench-press. Do more squats and deadlifting, your body is a machine that needs to stay balanced.

**This is a routine, you need a program**. Look-up 'Starting Strength', 'Strong Lifts', or 'The New Rules of Lifting'. All of those describe a complete program (i.e. multiple routines, how to do them, how many repetitions, tempo, etc.) from just starting out, to how to progress once you've made it past the newbie-gains stage.

Comment: so you mean at least 10 sets per muscle?.

Comment: Not 10 per muscle, a TOTAL of 15-20 per workout. Everyone has time limitations, but 9-10 sets per workout is a little slim.